# How can i post Array Data with Vue axios from Data obtained from an API

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, single-page-application

I am facing a problem where I have a form with inputs generated dynamically based on the results returned from the API. I can get the data successfully with Axios, but the problem is that when I want to post the entered data array by the user back to the api, I can't.

The Template is as shown here:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="getReference" class="form-material form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="item.id">
      <div class="card bg-light-inverse ribbon-wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="ribbon ribbon-danger">{{index + 1}}</div>
          <div class="row ribbon-content">

            <input v-model="item.id" />
            <label class="col-md-12 text-themecolor">Enter Amount To Pay</label>
            <div class="card col-md-12 m-t-10">
              <input
                v-model.number="item.amount"
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder
                max
                min
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button
    class="btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger waves-effect waves-dark"
  >Get Refrence</button>
</form>
```

And the JS code is:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: {},
      item: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    let uri = `/Api/${this.$route.params.id}/items`;
    this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
      this.items = response.data;
    });
  },
  // could go with computed method to check if there is data but well :
  methods: {
    getReference() {
      console.log(this.item);
      let uri = "/api/reference";
      this.axios.post(uri, this.item).then(response => {
        this.$router.push({ name: "fee" });
      });
    },
  }
};
```

When I try to post the form nothing is being sent and an error is thrown within the console `uncaught exception: Object`. I cant seem to figure out what is wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping the `items` as `item` in the template section and using `item` for binding the inputs. While sending you're using `this.item` in `axios`.

The input data is binding to the `items` itself since you're looping it. You can try sending `items` instead of `item` in the axios section.

```
  methods: {
    getReference() {
      console.log(this.item);
      let uri = "/api/reference";
      this.axios.post(uri, this.items).then(response => {
        this.$router.push({ name: "fee" });
      });
    },
  }
```

You can remove the `item` in data section since it will cause issue while using the same item for binding values in the input section.

Comment: hello @Rijosh, when i post Items instead, the whole object from the previous call is sent back to the server and none of the user entered data is seen in the said request.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to find the issue, as you suggested, that worked for me.